# pebble sdk installation on mac fails

Tags: sdk, failed-installation, pebble-sdk

I am trying to set up the dev environment on my Mac. I'm following the steps listed on the site (http://developer.getpebble.com/sdk/install/mac/). 
My installation fails at step#2 of Python libraries installation at line: "virtualenv --no-site-packages .env"

These are the errors I get when I execute the above line:

ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.5 (default, Mar 9 2014, 22:15:05) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]'

OSError: Command /Users/UserName/pebble...-dp1/.env/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1

Could anyone please help me resolve this?

Comment: What version of virtualenv do you have? (virtualenv --version)

Comment: My virtualenv's version is 1.10.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question. I resolved this issue by removing anaconda and re-installing python. (not an ideal solution, was my last resort)